# Position equation of $U(x)=-U_1[(\frac{x}{x_1})^3-(\frac{x}{x_1})^2 ]$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy

If $U(x)$ is given by $$U(x)=-U_1\left[\left(\frac{x}{x_1}\right)^3-\left(\frac{x}{x_1}\right)^2 \right]$$ can I find the position equation without harmonic aproximation?

I'm having problem with the nonlinear differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a classical cubic anharmonic oscillator, you would probably need to use elliptical functions (https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSolutionOfCubicAnharmonicOscillation/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the context. Is it a potential for the electric force or a mechanical one?
Modulo some constants, use the conservation of energy. It gives you $   \pm  \int_0^{x(t)}  \frac{dy}{ \sqrt{ \frac{2}{m} \big( E_{0}-U(y) \big)  } }  =t $

The exact solution can be found in terms of the F elliptic function but it requires to reduce the third degree polynomial to its standard form and the exact result is intractable.